# adding multiple model objects to a backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, collections, model

I am trying to add a couple of models to the collection

```
rolesSuccess: function(roles) {        
        var role1 = new Role({
        id: "1",
        Name:"TST1",
        Description:"Test 1"
        });

        var role2 = new Role({
        id: "2",
        Name:"TST2",
        Description:"Test 2"
        });

        roles = new Roles();
        roles.add(role1);
        roles.add(role2);
        this._context.roles(roles);  
    }
```

I only see one role being added at any point, just the first one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `append` is not a method for a `Backbone.Collection` (I am assuming, that's what `Roles` is). If that's the case, you should be using either `roles.add` or `roles.push`.

Comment: oops sorry, I had an add for both but I changed it to append to try. Yes, Roles is the Backbone Collection.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass an array of models to a backbone collection when you initialize it.

```
var roles = new Roles([role1, role2]);
```